# Swift: How to open file with associated application?

Tags: swift

I like to open a .xls file with Excel on macOS.
I only found examples for C# but not for Swift.

Bonus question: Is it possible to launch that file with Excel also, even if this file extension is not associated with Excel?

Comment: You can open a file with the associated program by using the terminal command `open /path/to/file`. You can do this in swift by using `NSTask`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(fileURL)` or `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile(fileURL.path!)` in order to open files by their default application.

If you want to force Excel, you can use `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile(fileURL.path!, withApplication: "Microsoft Excel")`.

If you prefer forcing Excel and using URL objects, then there's the excessive `openURLs(_:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers)`

Though it is not a big deal yet I am updating the syntax as per Swift 4.2 -

```
NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(fileURL!.path)
NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(fileURL!.path, withApplication: "Microsoft Excel")
NSWorkspace.shared.open([fileURL!], withAppBundleIdentifier: "com.microsoft.Excel", options: NSWorkspace.LaunchOptions.withErrorPresentation, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifiers: nil)
```

To get the Bundle Identifier of any app, use this command in your terminal

```
 osascript -e 'id of app "*app_name*"'
```